# Webhook handling with background job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, webhooks

I just wonder how I could handle webhook from third party API in general.

In my case, I need to handle Webhooks from Stripe.

So I use

- [StripeEvent](https://github.com/integrallis/stripe_event)  to handle and listen for the entrance of webhook handlers. It provides an easy to use interface for handling events from Stripe.

The main implementation is:

- take the ID from the POSTed event data
- stripe doesn't sign events, [so to verify by fetching event from Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#verifying-events).
- store events (id) and reject IDs that we've seen already to protect against replay attacks.

Everything works so far.

However, let's assume that

- **handling little complex logic within in webhook hanlder**
- **listening many webhook requests**

In this case, I feel I need to consider to use **background job**.

[Best practices in stripe doc](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#best-practices)

> If your webhook script performs complex logic, or makes network calls, it's possible the script would timeout before Stripe sees its complete execution. For that reason, you may want to have your webhook endpoint immediately acknowledge receipt by returning a 2xx HTTP status code, >and then perform the rest of its duties.

Here is my code,
I've just wondered which part I should bundle and enqueue?

```
StripeEvent.event_retriever = lambda do |params|
  return nil if StripeWebhook.exists?(stripe_id: params[:id])
  StripeWebhook.create!(stripe_id: params[:id])

  return Stripe::Event.construct_from(params.deep_symbolize_keys) if Rails.env.test? # fetching the event from Stripe API

  return Stripe::Event.retrieve(params[:id])
end

StripeEvent.configure do |events|
  events.subscribe 'invoice.created', InvoiceCreated.new # handling the invoice.created event in service object
  events.subscribe 'invoice.payment_succeeded', InvoicePaymentSucceeded.new
 ...
end
```

Comment: all of it i guess

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, just send all of it by serializing the `Stripe::Event` instance to a string with [Marshal::dump](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Marshal.html#method-c-dump), then deserialize back to a `Stripe::Event` in your background worker with [Marshal::load](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Marshal.html#method-c-load).

We also wanted to process the webhook requests in the background using our [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) system, which stores the jobs in a database table and the job arguments in a string column.

To do that we first needed to serialize the `Stripe::Event` to a string in our `StripeEvent.configure` block:

```
# event is an instance of Stripe::Event
serialized_event = Marshal::dump(event)
```

Then we queue the background job rather than handling it synchronously, passing our serialized event as a string to where it is stored (in our case a database table) to await being processed.

Then our background worker code can deserialize the string it reads back to a `Stripe::Event`:

```
event = Marshal::load(serialized_event)
```